# std::string::append(std::string) erroneous output

Tags: c++, string, append

I'm trying to make a simple text encrypter (not all functions are complete) but I have a specific problem that I would like some help with. I stopped at this point in coding and added some commented documentation for testing:

In the function algorithm():
lines 16-25 are appending the index of std::string ck[] to std::string KEY inside the *nested* loop. The *outside* loop is running for the measure of PASSWORD.size() and checking each PASSWORD.substr(...) against all ck[].

The output, however, only turns out to be the index values of the first and last character of PASSWORD. eg. If PASSWORD=abc KEY outputs 0002. I want the whole PASSWORD to become KEY (as dictated).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>


std::string PASSWORD, KEY, ENCRYPTED_TEXT;

void algorithm(std::string note){
    ENCRYPTED_TEXT.append(note);

    /**STANDARD RULESET**/
    std::string ck[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

    for(int x=0;x<PASSWORD.size();x++){
        for(int y=0;y<sizeof(ck)/4;y++){ 
            if(PASSWORD.substr(x,x+1)==ck[y]){
                std::stringstream ind;
                if(y>9) ind << y+1;
                else ind << "0" << y;
                KEY.append(ind.str());
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\nKey is " << KEY;

    //make_file(ENCRYPTED_TEXT);
}

void qn_setup(){
    bool ask=true;
    while(ask=true){
        std::string check1="", check2="";
        std::cout << "Type a password:\n";
        std::cin >> check1;
        std::cout << "Confirm password:\n";
        std::cin >> check2;
        if(check1==check2) { 
            PASSWORD=check1;
            ENCRYPTED_TEXT=check1;
            ask=false; 
            break; }
        else { std::cout << "\nPasswords did not match.\n"; }
    }
}

int main(){
    qn_setup();
    algorithm(""); //testing key
}
```

There aren't any syntax errors, just logic errors.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is.  Please can you construct a simpler program that focuses on the core problem?  (i.e. strip out all the stuff that's not relevant to your question.)

Comment: `sizeof(ck)/4` ... I'm very suspicious of this. You can't just assume that `sizeof(std::string) == 4`...

Comment: Because of #defining keywords `true` and `false`, your program invokes undefined behavior, so any result is possible.

Comment: I guess I should mention that the important members are PASSWORD and KEY and the important member functions are qn_setup() and algorithm(). Everything else can really be ignored as initializing.

Comment: @Tadeusz Kopec sorry I didn't fully understand - what do the booleans have to do with the for loops?

Comment: @ShavBhattacharyya: If that is the case, please remove those irrelevant functions from your example code, so that we can focus on the important stuff.

Comment: Standard 17.6.4.3.1 pt 2 says "A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords"

Comment: @OliCharlesworth edited it for tidiness

Comment: @TadeuszKopec I got rid of the header definitions, same problem. The booleans have nothing to do with the for loop, no offence.

Comment: Should it actually say while(ask=true) and not while(ask) or while(ask==true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> string substr ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos ) const;
>
> ```
> Generate substring
>
> Returns a string object with its contents initialized to a substring of the 
> current object.
>
> This substring is the character sequence that starts at character position 
> pos and has a length of n characters.
> ```

so your check has to be:

```
PASSWORD.substr(x,1)==ck[y] /* instead of PASSWORD.substr(x,x+1) */
```

Comment: Thankyou very much haha now for some morning coffee

Comment: I've lost count of have many times I've got that one wrong. Some days I really want different types for ordinals and cardinals.